# How can I two-way bind a TextBox to a code-behind property in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, properties, code-behind

I cannot get any new entries in the textbox:txtMyString to set to the property MyString. What am I missing here?

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMyString" Text='<%# MyString %>' runat="server" />

private string myString;
protected string MyString { get { return myString; } set { myString = value; } }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        myString = "1 way test works";

    DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're doing two-way databinding, you need to use the Bind() method of the databinder.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtMyString" Text='<%# Bind("MyString") %>' runat="server" />
```

However, last time I checked, this was only supported if the textbox was inside a templated control such as Gridview, FormView or DetailsView.