# asp.net binding problem

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have in my code behind the following property

```
public string Firstname {get;set;}
```

when I want to bind it to some textbox I do the following:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtFirstname" Text='<%# Bind("Firstname") %>'/>
```

then I want value put in this textbox to be set in my Firstname property (because I want to process it e.g. save this value) in my presenter. 
Why it doesn't work?
EDIT
Here is the aspx

```
<formview runat="server" ID="myFormView">
                <p>Firstname <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName"  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Firstname") %>' /></p>
                <p>Lastname <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" /></p>
                <input type="button" title="send" runat="server" id="btnSend" />
            </formview>
```

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1997735/how-can-i-two-way-bind-a-textbox-to-a-code-behind-property-in-asp-net and also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871404/asp-net-data-bind-two-way-bi-directional-from-code-behind

Comment: I post everything needed. No other things are set in code behind (except a method that is called when submit button is clicked)

Comment: Are you calling Page.DataBind() in Page_Load?

Comment: We need more info. Are other controls binding as expected? Is this happening in a postback? Is the textbox in formview? If so is the formview in the proper mode? etc. Some markup may help.

Comment: You should probably show us the actual mark up and code that you are using...that formview doesn't have an ID or datasource. If it had an ID that would lead me to beleive you are manually setting the datasrouce in the code which may be part of problem depending on how you are doing it. If you don't want to post secret info change the Ids and hide only the confidential info.

Comment: i've added ID for a formview but I don't set DataSource for it.Still the same problem

Comment: Then how is the formview supposed to know where to get the data from?

Comment: because I thought it will bind to Page by default. How can I then set a datasource for this? I cannot see this property when using myFormView in code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will bind in the page load but you have to tell it what to bind to in mark up or in code. You didn't say where or how you're storing your data and it sounds like you are trying to insert new data so...

Here is a tutorial on the sqldatasource.
[SQL Datasource Tutorial](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs)

Here is a turorial on the formview:
[Formview Tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288035.aspx)

Here is a simple one I whipped up...(NOTE: I did not test the below code, so if I forgot somehting my apologies, but it should give you a good start).

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" 
    runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="Connection string for your database here." 
    SelectCommand="SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM YourTable"
    >
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

```
    <asp:FormView ID="frmYourForm" DefaultMode="Insert" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="Update" runat="server">Update</asp:LinkButton>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <br />
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" CommandName="Insert" runat="server">Insert</asp:LinkButton>
            </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
```

**EDIT:**  Fixed the links to the tutorials...I didn't realize the orginal link didn't show info on the formview.